Combining the two conformal mapping equations

The mapping function ${Z_{\rm{1}}}$, which transforms the outside region of a unit circle (in the $\zeta$-plane) onto the outside region of the unit circle with two unequal radial aligned cracks (in the
${Z_{\rm{1}}}$-plane), is expressed as follows: $${Z_{\rm{1}}}{\rm{ =
}}M(\zeta {\rm{ + }}{{\rm{1}} \over \zeta }){\rm{ + }}N + Q(\zeta )$$
where $$Q(\zeta ){\rm{ = }}\zeta \sqrt {{{\rm{1}} \over {{\zeta
^{\rm{2}}}}}({{(M(\zeta  + {1 \over \zeta }) + N)}^2} - 1)} $$ M and N
are real constants. The mapping function  $Z = \omega (\zeta )$ for
a plane with an elliptical hole as follows: $$Z = \omega (\zeta ) =
\lambda (\zeta  + {\omega  \over \zeta })$$ $$\lambda  = {{a + b}
 \over 2}, w  = {{a - b} \over {a + b}}$$
Where a and b are the semi-axes of the ellipse. Combining the two
mapping functions, the mapping function for the outside region of the
unit circle in the ${\zeta}$-plane onto the outside region of the
elliptical hole with two unequal aligned cracks in the Z-plane is
$$\omega (\zeta ) = \lambda ((1 + w)(M(\zeta  + {1 \over \zeta }) + N) + (1 - w)Q(\zeta ))$$

However, I combined the two conformal mapping functions:
$$\omega (\zeta ) = \lambda (M(\zeta {\rm{ + }}{{\rm{1}} \over \zeta }){\rm{ + }}N + Q(\zeta ) + {w \over {M(\zeta {\rm{ + }}{{\rm{1}} \over \zeta }){\rm{ + }}N + Q(\zeta )}})$$
Can I further simplify, or is there a problem with this method of combining?
